# How to resolve SQL error 772

Tags: windows-10, windows-11, sql, odbc, sql-server-2005

Using the preloaded ODBC driver version 10.00.22621.1992 on Windows 11 and added the data source in System DSN. When it tries to test the connection I get this error (picture below).
SqlState:01000
SQL Server Error: 772[image]
The database is SQL Server 2005. This is an issue on one of the client machines.  It is running on Windows 11. No other machines using this ODBC driver has Windows 11 yet.
As per my reserarch it has something to do with enabling TLS.

I have enabled the TLS from Control Panel --> Network and Internet --> Internet Options
and from the registery.
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols
Added the TLS 1.0 and Client as keys, added Dword "DisabledByDefault" to 0 and "Enabled" to 1.

I did this for TLS 1.1,1.2. Picture below
[image]

- The issue is with Windows 11.  It works on Windows 10 but when Windows 11 is loaded it gives the error, loading Windows 10 again gets rid of the error
- Forced encryption is set to OFF on the SQL Server
- SQL Server 2005 is hosted on Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 1 (x64)

Answer (score 0):

You state you're using driver version 10.00.22621.1992, which is **very** much outdated. [Download a newer version, 18.3.1.1 from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16) and test it, on one or more machines, against the existing SQL Server DB back end, **before deploying it to all**.

No version of TLS prior to 1.3 should be required for any use, since [previous versions have been declared risks for some years](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security). Likely those in charge of site security for you organization would take a dim view of resurrecting the deprecated versions! If SQL Server 2005 cannot be used with a secure drivers, that might need to be updated, as well. Just as [knob-and-tube electric wiring](https://www.gervaiselectric.com/understanding-knob-and-tube-wiring-in-old-or-historic-homes/) is considered unsafe, so are those deprecated protocols.

Comment: had tried that already. It doesn't work either.